# I want to rewrite a url using the user's mysql id number

Tags: .htaccess

I am new to this forum and very new to regexp and rewrites in htaccess.  I have looked for an answer to what I am doing and cannot seem to find one that I can apply; although that does not mean there is not one there.

I have a rewrite rule that works great when logged in, shown below, but as soon as you log out (no id number in url) the system seems to break.

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule    ^([0-9]+)?$    /a_folder/index.php?userid=$1    [NC,L]
```

I want to be able to have anyone visit the main paqe without locking up and when a user is logged in, to be visiting the "a_folder/index.php?userid=$1" file.  Im sure there is an answer, I am just having trouble wrapping my brain around regexp's and RewriteCond's.

There is a second part I needed that I forgot to mention.  If the user id in the url is the user id of that session, I want to direct them to a_folder.  But if the id is different between the url and the session, I wanto direct them to b_folder.  How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://domain.com/ :

```
RewriteRule    ^$    /a_folder/logged_out.php    [NC,L]
```

http://domain.com/123

```
RewriteRule    ^([0-9]+)?$    /a_folder/index.php?userid=$1    [NC,L]
```

I'm not sure if I understood the question ...

Comment: That may be it.  I think the root index.php file of domain.com is what is confusing the issue.  If someone types in www.domain.com, they would need to be redirected to the "/a_folder/logged_out.php" page. Correct?

Comment: That did it!  I knew the answer have to be a simple one.  I was trying to redirect the logged out user back to the index page at domain.com.  Creating the logged out page and adding the 1st rewrite rule above in addition to the existing one did it.  Thanks Peter!

Comment: There is a second part I needed that I forgot to mention. If the user id in the url is the user id of that session, I want to direct them to a_folder. But if the id is different between the url and the session, I wanto direct them to b_folder. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Make redirection at first lines in index.php to desired url for ex.: http://domain.com/d/123. In htaccess you can use only COOKIES and it's not safe to auth in php using cookie.

Comment: htaccess should determine if 123 is the session id of the user or not. Whether redirected to folder "a_folder" or "b_folder", I want to be able to display the url as "www.domain.com/123".  Are COOKIES a secure way of doing this in htaccess?

Comment: You can use cookies in htaccess, but you must use php as well just for security reason. If cookie['userid'] != session['userid'] redirect to error page.